# Как сравнить две строки чтобы узнать на каких символах отличаются

Tags: java

у меня есть 2 строки и я хочу узнать какой символ не правильный по сравнению с другой. Пробовал `compare`, `equals`, но они дают не те ответы.

```
String a1="Text";
String a2="Taxt";
/*Some code*/
System.out.println();
```

Вывод

```
Diferent in position 1
```

Вот попробовал написать код он определяет где ошибка но у меня складывается впечатление что он не очень эффективный

```
      String vvedeno="Строка для сравнения 1";
      String nadovvesti="сТрока для сравнения 2";

      int i=nadovvesti.length();
      if(i==vvedeno.length()) {
          StringBuffer line=new StringBuffer();
          boolean[] srav = new boolean[i];
          for (int j=0; j < i; j++) {
              if (vvedeno.charAt(j) == nadovvesti.charAt(j))
                  srav[j] = true;
          }
          for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
              if(!srav[j])
                  line.append("_");
              else line.append(" ");
          }
          System.out.println(nadovvesti);
          System.out.println(line.toString());
          System.out.println(vvedeno);
```

Результат работы

```
Строка для сравнения 1
__                   _
сТрока для сравнения 2
```

Comment: Конечно не очень эффективный. Зачем делать второй цикл, если все можно сделать в одном.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот попробовал написать код он определяет где ошибка но у меня складывается впечатление что он не очень эффективный

```
`String vvedeno="Строка для сравнения 1"; String nadovvesti="сТрока для сравнения 2";

  int i=nadovvesti.length();
  if(i==vvedeno.length()) {
      StringBuffer line=new StringBuffer();
      for (int j=0; j < i; j++) {
          if (vvedeno.charAt(j) == nadovvesti.charAt(j))
            line.append(" ");
          else line.append("_");
      }
      System.out.println(nadovvesti);
      System.out.println(line.toString());
      System.out.println(vvedeno);`
```

Результат работы

```
Строка для сравнения 1
__                   _
сТрока для сравнения 2
```